# List box event is not firing inside update panel control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load records from database on selection of ListBox's SelectedIndexChanged event. I am getting all nicely without using the Update Panel control in my form. Now i wanted to use the Update Panel control such that my form does not postback every time i select an item from the listbox. I tried but wouldn't work as expected. Please help me to overcome this problem i am facing.

.aspx code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="450px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstTest_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtReport" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtImression" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lstTest" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.cs code behind

```
protected void lstTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int _serviceid = Convert.ToInt32(lstTest.SelectedValue);

    txtReport.Text = string.Empty;
    txtImression.Text = string.Empty;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "[get_rad_results]";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _serviceid;
    cmd.Connection = con;


    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            txtReport.Text = dr["Report"].ToString();
            txtImression.Text = dr["Impression"].ToString();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error occured: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: use PostBackTrigger instead of AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Comment: are there any script errors on your page? can you verify that your `lstTest_SelectedIndexChanged(..)` is executed? I am not quite sure what *but wouldn't work as expected* means exactly

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you did miss an according *[script manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)* in aspx code? I did a small example that worked for me.

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListBox1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // demo values
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add("value " + i);
        }

    }
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

In case I did miss anything please let me know.

Comment: I do have ScriptManager added on page.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know what you think is wrong/inappropriate!